# When pytorch tensor is expanded, which dimension is expanded first?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to know whether the tensor `a` become `torch.ones(1,3,2)` and then `torch.ones(5,3,2)` or does it become `torch.ones(5,1,2)` and then `torch.ones(5,3,2)` during the addition operation?

My code:

```
import torch
a = torch.ones(1,1,2)
b = torch.ones(5,3,2)
c = a + b
print(c)
```

The result:

```
tensor([[[2., 2.],
         [2., 2.],
         [2., 2.]],

        [[2., 2.],
         [2., 2.],
         [2., 2.]],

        [[2., 2.],
         [2., 2.],
         [2., 2.]],

        [[2., 2.],
         [2., 2.],
         [2., 2.]],

        [[2., 2.],
         [2., 2.],
         [2., 2.]]])
```

Comment: This is called [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics). The shape of `a` is always `(1,1,2)`

Comment: I guess the OP is trying to implement broadcasting from scratch, so he asked the order of shape change.

Comment: @jasonwong Yes,I mean the order of shape change.

Comment: I don't think it is a good way to change the shapes for broadcasting. With tensors of the same shape, say `(5,3,2)`. You iterate over `(i,j,k)` and set `c[i,j,k]=a[i,j,k]+b[i,j,k]`. With different but broadcastable shapes, say `(1,1,2)` and `(5,3,2)`, you simply **do not** iterate over the broadcasted dimensions: `c[i,j,k]=a[0,0,k]+b[i,j,k]`. Since no shape change occurs, we don't really need to talk about the order of shape change.